# TCP socket Read

Tags: c, tcp

I don't know how to describe my question so I give an example.

Bill sends data to Alice via TCP scoket. The code below is :

```
write(socketfd,buff,10000);
```

And Alice already knew that the data size is always 10000. The code below is :

```
read(socketfd,buff,10000);
```

The question is that is it possible Alice get a data small than 10000 and she needs to read the socket again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! TCP sockets provide a stream interface and it is quite possible that data is delivered in more than one part.

The receiver should continue reading until all data has been received.

```
while (totalRead < expectedSize) {
    result = read(socketfd,buff + totalRead, expectedSize-totalRead);
    if (result < 0) {
        // nothing read, check for errors
    } else {
        totalRead += result;
        if (result == 0) {
             // Other end shutdown before sending the expected amount of data
        }
    }
}
```

The same is true for writing:

```
while (written < totalSize) {
    result = write(socketfd,buff + written, totalSize - written);
    if (result < 0) {
        // nothing written, check for errors
    } else {
        written += result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should deal with `read` returning 0 (which it will on end of file) otherwise, if the stream is closed normally before it has read `totalSize` the program will loop forever.

Comment: @JeremyP Thanks. Check added.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, TCP is not packet-oriented and the network stack might decide to deliver incoming data in any "chunk size".

It's possible that you get the first 10% and then there's a few seconds of network delay, then TCP might deliver the data it's gotten so far, for instance.

With any kind of I/O that is not explicitly packet-oriented, you should always loop the read until you've gotten the expected amount in total. This is true for reading from plain local files, too.

Answer (score 2):

What if there is an error? What if you need to check for a closed connection? Both those are reported by `read` using the returned value.

And remember that first of all TCP is a *streaming* protocol without fixed packet sizes, so a single call may not read all the data if not all have been received yet. And secondly remember that the underlying protocols may not have that large packets for its transfer and will split up the data into smaller chunks that you will receive one at a time.

So yes, *always* check the actual size the `read` call have read.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is that is it possible Alice get a data small than 10000 and she needs to read the socket again.

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

yes and the same for write. you have to check the ret value of write.

Answer (score 1):

Read typically returns as soon as SOME data is read. It returns the actual number of bytes read, and a negative number for an error.

TCP on the other hand make no guarantee that the data will come all at once. So you should repeatedly cann checking the return code until you have completed to read t8ge desired length of data.